# What is the difference between LocalOffsetX vs GlobalOffsetX, LocalOffsetY vs GlobalOffsetY & LocalOffsetZ vs GlobalOffsetZ

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

What do these terms mean LocalOffsetZ and GlobalOffsetZ. I know they are used in projection and i read the msdn. But i don't quiet seem to understand. My vision is not getting clear as to when would you use LocalOffsetZ as against GlobalOffsetZ and viceversa. Can anybody provide a simple example that would clear my thinking?

Thanks in advance :)